# Calling a variable from one function to another function in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to send an email through python. I have different def's that hold the variables that contain the email username and email password etc.. Then I have another def that actual sends the email, but it needs the variable that contains the email username and password etc.. How can I call the variables from the different def's? Sorry for the weird wording. I don't know how else to say it :P Thanks!

```
def get_email_address():
    #the code to open up a window that gets the email address
    Email = input
def get_email_username():
    #the code to open up a window that gets email username
    Email_Username = input

    #same for the email recipient and email password

def send_email():
    #here I need to pull all the variables from the other def's
    #code to send email
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to return values in your helper functions and call those functions from your main `send_email()` function, assigning the returned values to variables.  Something like this:

```
def get_email_address():
    #the code to open up a window that gets the email address
    Email = input
    return Email

def get_email_username():
    #the code to open up a window that gets email username
    Email_Username = input
    return Email_Username

#same for the email recipient and email password

def send_email():
    # variables from the other def's
    email_address = get_email_address()
    email_username = get_email_username()

    #code to send email
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question though. I have a def inside a def. How do I access that. If I used get_email_address() it would open up the window asking me for my email but I already entered it in so I made a def just containing the return Email. but now that gives me a def inside a def so how would I access it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean - but I would suggest perhaps not using nested functions.