# Maya Python & Pyside: pass value returned from a method with multiple args into another method

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, maya

I'm beginning some Python UI with Pyside in Maya 2016.

I am trying to make a function in my UI class that gets all the values of a few widgets.

Here's the function snippets from my class that are involved:

```
class UI_Window_to_Rename(uiWindow_form, uiWindow_base):

    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):

        self.create_connections()

    def create_connections(self):

        self.maxDist_spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.get_vert_distance)
        self.setVerts_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_all_settings)

    def get_vert_distance(self, value):

        return str(value)

    def get_all_settings(self):
    # This doesn't work. How to I pass the argument from 
    #  get_vert_distance into this function?
# TypeError: get_vert_distance() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)


        vert_dist = self.get_vert_distance(value)
```

I basically want `get_all_settings` to manipulate the values of other functions I pass in. But I'm not sure how to do that since `get_vert_distance` uses 2 arguments.

Kind of similar to this question, but I think this is more complex?

[Calling a variable from one function to another function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768856/calling-a-variable-from-one-function-to-another-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this wrong. I should have just made a function to query the current value of the `maxDist_spinBox` widget with:

```
def get_all_settings(self):
    print self.maxDist_spinBox.value()
```

https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QSpinBox.html?highlight=spinbox#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QSpinBox.value