# undefined error when passing list as parameter in python

Tags: python, list, parameters, scope

So I previously had my code set-up to access a list that was declared outside functions making it a global variable, for the task I was assigned the lecturer is insisting that we do not use global variables.  So now I have the following code which obviously gives a "data_set undefined error"

The idea being that I create a list from a csv file and then pass that list to several other functions so that I can get elements from the data_set list and create new outputs.

```
import csv
import sys

def print_menu():
    print("ACME WEATHER DATA APP")
    print("1) Choose weather data file")
    print("2) See data for selected day")
    print("3) Calculate average statistics for the data")
    print("4) Print a scatterplot of the average temperatures")
    print("0) Quit program")

def loadFile(x):
    data_set = []
    data_set.clear()
    with open(x, "r") as readfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(readfile, delimiter= ';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            data_set.append(row)
    print("Loaded weather data from", (x[0:-4]).capitalize())
    print()
    return data_set    

def avgDay(x, data_set):
    for line in data_set:
        if(len(x) == 5 and (x[3:5] + "-" + x[0:2]) in line[0]):
           print("The weather on", x, "was on average", line[2], "centigrade")


def lowHigh(x, data_set):
    for line in data_set:
        if(len(x) == 5 and (x[3:5] + "-" + x[0:2]) in line[0]):
            print("The lowest temperature was", line[3], "and the highest temperature was", line[4])


def rain(x, data_set):
    for line in data_set:
        if(len(x) == 5 and (x[3:5] + "-" + x[0:2]) in line[0]):
            print("There was", line[1],"mm rain")
            print()

def avgMonth(data_set):
    avgList= []
    for line in data[1:]:
        avgList.append(line[2])
    avgList= [float(i) for i in avgList]
    avg = sum(avgList)/len(avgList)
    print("The average temperature for the 25 day period was", round(avg,1))


def avgLow(data_set):
    avgList= []
    for line in data[1:]:
        avgList.append(line[3]) 
    avgList= [float(i) for i in avgList]
    avg = sum(avgList)/len(avgList)
    print("The average lowest temperature was", round(avg,1))


def avgHigh(data_set):
    avgList= []
    for line in data[1:]:
        avgList.append(line[4])  
    avgList= [float(i) for i in avgList]
    avg = sum(avgList)/len(avgList)

    print("The average highest temperature was", round(avg,1))
    print()

def print_tempLine(day, month, temp):
    print(day + "." + month + " ", end="")
    print("   "*(temp+5) + "-", end="")
    print()


def print_tempAxis():
    print("      ", end="")
    for i in range(-5,16):
        print("{:02d} ".format(i), end="")
    print()

def scatPlot(data_set):
    for line in data[1:]:
            day_month=line[0].split("-")
            temp=int(round(float(line[2]),0))
            print_tempLine(day_month[2],day_month[1],temp)
            print_tempAxis()
            print()

def menu_number():
    number = int(input("Choose what to do: "))
    if (number) == 1:
        x = input("Give name of the file: " )
        loadFile(x)
        print_menu()
        menu_number()

    elif (number) == 2:
        x = input("Give a date (dd.mm): ")
        avgDay(x, data_set)
        lowHigh(x, data_set)
        rain(x, data_set)
        print_menu()
        menu_number()

    elif (number) == 3:
        avgMonth(data_set)
        avgLow(data_set)
        avgHigh(data_set)
        print_menu()
        menu_number()

    elif (number) == 4:
        scatPlot(data_set)
        print_menu()
        menu_number()

    elif (number) == 0:
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print("\n Your selection is invalid, please try again!\n")
        print_menu()
        menu_number()

print_menu()
menu_number()
```

I understand that when I return data_set in my loadFile(x) that it needs to be assigned to a variable somehow so that it can be accessed outside the local scope, I just am not sure how that is done. I have tried changing `loadFile(x)` to `data_set = loadFile(x)` within menu_number function, this just resulted in it giving the following error "local variable 'data_set' referenced before assignment".  So is there something I have missed or do I need to re-write the code somehow?

Edit:  Sorry did not realize I needed to provide full stack trace error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\XAMK\python scripts\test.py", line 126, in <module>
    menu_number()
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\XAMK\python scripts\test.py", line 95, in menu_number
    menu_number()
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\XAMK\python scripts\test.py", line 99, in menu_number
    avgDay(x, data_set)
NameError: name 'data_set' is not defined
```

Edit 2: csv sample code

```
"DateTime";"Precipitation";"Mean temperature";"Minimum temperature";"Maximum temperature";"Typical maximum temperature";"Typical maximum temperature";"Typical minimum temperature";"Typical minimum temperature";"Fairly typical maximum temperature";"Fairly typical maximum temperature";"Fairly typical minimum temperature";"Fairly typical minimum temperature"
"2019-10-06";0;4;0.4;6.8;10.3;11.9;4.5;7.2;7.6;13.8;0.9;9.8
"2019-10-07";0.1;4.4;2.6;7.8;10.1;11.8;4.4;7;7.4;13.6;0.8;9.7
"2019-10-08";0;4.9;2.3;7.2;10;11.6;4.2;6.9;7.2;13.4;0.6;9.5
"2019-10-09";1.1;4.8;1.8;7.6;9.8;11.4;4.1;6.7;6.9;13.3;0.5;9.4
```

Comment: Post the full error message, including the stack trace. You **really** need to be providing a [mcve], not just dumping your whole code here.

Comment: Functions return **values**, not names. If you want to use the value that was returned, you need to... use it, for example by storing it somewhere. Writing `add(1, 2)` (supposing that you implemented such a function) is the same as if you wrote `1 + 2` - the `3` result doesn't do anything by itself (and it doesn't matter what name, if any, the `add` function uses internally for that result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you can provide an example csv file so that I can test the workflow.  But it looks like the problem is that you call `loadFile(x)`, and it has a `return` statement, but nothing is set to that return statement. So you are on the right track with `data_set = loadFile(x)`.  The problem is, when you call the `menu_number` function again, variable values are not preserved.  So on that second call, `data_set` lost its meaning.

You can fix this by passing the value of data_set to the function, so your menu_number would look more like

```
def menu_number(data_set=None):
    number = int(input("Choose what to do: "))
    if (number) == 1:
        x = input("Give name of the file: " )
        data_set=loadFile(x)
        print_menu()
        # passing data_set value along
        # with the call
        menu_number(data_set)

    elif (number) == 2:
        x = input("Give a date (dd.mm): ")
        avgDay(x, data_set)
        lowHigh(x, data_set)
        rain(x, data_set)
        print_menu()
        # passing data_set to preserve it
        menu_number(data_set)

    elif (number) == 3:
        avgMonth(data_set)
        avgLow(data_set)
        avgHigh(data_set)
        print_menu()
        # passing data_set to preserve it
        menu_number(data_set)

    elif (number) == 4:
        scatPlot(data_set)
        print_menu()
        # passing data_set to preserve it
        menu_number(data_set)

    elif (number) == 0:
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print("\n Your selection is invalid, please try again!\n")
        print_menu()
        # passing data_set to preserve it
        menu_number(data_set)
```

In this example, data_set is an optional variable.  If you call `menu_number()`, `data_set` is `None`.  But on your calls of `menu_number(data_set)`, you can reuse the value.

Making data_set an optional parameter will prevent any undefined errors.  Passing it back to itself will prevent you from needing to read the csv file over and over again.

Comment: Hmm, this could be what I am missing, is there someway to upload one of the files I am using along with the question in here?

Comment: Honestly not sure.  If you just pasted in a few rows of the csv in a code block, like you did with your function, that would do the trick for me.

I expanded my example to show the entire function update.

Comment: Added in first few lines from one of the csv files I am working with, will test out what you suggested to see if that resolves my problems thanks.

Comment: Thanks. If you have trouble let me know.  I tested with that and spotted another bug, in some of your function you have 'for line in data[1:]', but the variable you pass is data_set.  So you'll need to update that too.

Comment: Looks like you have hit the nail on the head!  It threw up some more errors, but that was because I had been trying some other changes so data_set was set as data in a few other functions.  Just about to change those now and re-run code.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.  If you can accept that answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: All I can say is wow and thank you very much.  Wasn't sure what was going wrong but if I understand what you are saying, every time it ran my menu_number from menu, it was wiping the value that data_set had stored,  so that was why it was passed as a parameter there?

Comment: Exactly.  A variable only exists for the duration of the function call.  So user clicks 1, we read in data_set, call the function again. Even though menu is being called a second time, the data_set only had value in that first call.  With our change, that data_set value keeps getting passed back into the function, so that it's not lost.

Comment: Again, thank you so much, haven't had much practical experience with python and the tutorials I have been going through haven't dealt with passing return values through multiple functions like I needed.

Answer (score 0):

1) you must do `data_set = loadFile()` in order to recieve the list `loadFile()` returns.

2) now, regarding the `"local variable 'data_set' referenced before assignment"` error, it probably happens when `number` is not equal to one, which causes your code to skip `data_set = loadFile()`, and combined with the fact that `data_set` is not recognized **outside** of the `if` statement as long as you don't declare it in a higher scope (the beginning of the function, for example), function like `avgDay(x, data_set)` will not recognize `data_set` as a variable.
to solve this i suggest:

1) declare `data_set` in a higher scope.

2) every action the user can choose that relays on `data_set` being initialized in `loadFile()` must also include this initialization